# jquery tags move drag and reorganizing based on ID and mouse move

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I would like to get tags like here https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ under "Categorizing tags"

I am struggling with this:

1. I need to be able to reorganize tags with mouse (to be able to switch order of tags)
2. I have predefined set of tags and I would like also have list of available tags shown (when user clicks on new tag entering, he should be able to see available unused tags /without need to start writing/)
3. tags should have visible text and hidden ID (like "1:Amsterdam, 2:Paris, 3:Berlin" and these IDs are specific for each city).

help or link for any component (jquery/bootstrap) which is able to handel this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pretty tag library for that.

https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html

Comment: thanks, but it does not shows me list of predefined tags. And another thing - I need specific pair "ID:city" for each city. It this possible?

Comment: what, I don't understand?

Comment: 2.) I have predefined set of tags and I would like also have list of available tags shown (when user clicks on new tag entering, he should be able to see available unused tags /without need to start writing/)

Comment: 3.) tags should have visible text and hidden ID (like "1:Amsterdam, 2:Paris, 3:Berlin" and these IDs are specific for each city).

Comment: for your second question, you can use `Autocomplete` method, watch in above link

Comment: third question is not related to the library because you can also make this possible with simple jQuery code

Comment: thanks, is looks promising. I tried to set minLength:0 to show autocomplete after I click into input bus it is not working this way. Could you please tell me how to force autocomplete when I just click inside input or after hitting enter (when another tag is inserted)?

Comment: Don't know about it, you can make new question about it. Thanks !!